# Switching a UHF signal between outputs?

Tags: rf

I have a 1258MHz transmitter running at 1W output power.  I want to switch it between two antennas while it's in the field.

Can I use a pair of any standard MOSFETs for this, assuming the power dissipation of the FET is adhered to?  If not, what do I look for in the datasheet to know that a particular FET is appropriate?

If a FET isn't appropriate, what kind of device would be?  I'm not oscillating the thing at anything more than 1hz (at worst!), so I don't think I need the special "RF" components.

Comment: Any "standard anything" and "1.3GHz" don't go together. You'll be "oscillating the thing" at 1258MHz, which is considerably more than 1Hz.

Comment: Start looking at high frequency microstrip design, high frequency transistors, S parameters, and impedance matching. Or find a commercially available RF switch box.

Comment: 1 watt is 30 dBm, so not too much power. Skyworks, Peregrine, Analog Devices, Macom all sell Multi port RF switched to do this, I'd strongly recommend buying one of these instead of trying to roll your own. Read the datasheets carefully, you may have to turn the output of your transmitter off when switching so you're not switching hot.

Comment: Look up PIN diodes and RF relays.

Comment: @TomCarpenter: I meant I'm not trying to charge & discharge a gate at 1.3ghz.  I didn't know if a biased NPN bipolar could pass a 1.3ghz signal through it or not, or a source-drain could do the same once a gate is charged.

Comment: @insta you're feeding in a 1.3GHz signal, which means you are causing the channel voltage to rise up and down at 1.3GHz. The gate capacitance is between the gate metal and the transistor channel, so moving the source up and down while keeping the gate constant is pretty much equivalent to moving the gate up and down while keeping the source constant.